# C conflicting types for function with different arguments

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have a struct with 2 initialiser functions which take different types of arguments:

```
struct myStruct;
typedef struct myStruct *myStruct;

INFNumber *myStructMake(long long arg);
INFNumber *myStructMake(char *arg);
```

I get a `conflicting types for 'myStructMake'` error on the second declaration. Is C not capable of having 2 identically named functions which take different parameters? Or is it for some other reason?

Comment: C is not C++ - it doesn't have function overloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is C not capable of having 2 identically named functions which take
>   different parameters

That's right, no overloading. You have to use different names or choose some other scheme (like passing additional arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with different data-types needs in the same structure type is to do something like this :

```
struct s_my_struct
{
  void *data;
  char data_type;
}
```

with :

```
#define DATA_TYPE_LONGLONGP 'm'
#define DATA_TYPE_CHARP 's'
```

and use like this :

```
if (mystruct.data_type == DATA_TYPE_CHARP)
{
  // use of ((char*)mystruct.data)
}
else if (mystruct.data_type == DATA_TYPE_LONGLONG)
{
  // use of ((long long*)mystruct.data)
}
```

Beware as you always have to use a pointer and not flat types because the struct stores pointer-size data.

Comment: I'm not actually storing the initialisation argument straight away, so I don't actually need to keep it in a `void*` along with its type. The given value is processed into a completely different structure, and not stored.